# how make multi lang website without loading all data again?

Tags: html, css

I have basic HTML website [webcovid19.live](https://webcovid19.live/) with many iframe tags,
How can I create multi lang website without loading all stuff again ?
...Just to load new text without iframes.

Comment: You really need to eleborate and show a [reprex] as you are way to generic and will get downvoted/closed. Have you tried using an attribute selector like [lang="EN"] [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google translate. Its the fastest way to translate a website.please give enough information what you really want to do which language you are using

Comment: OK Sorry for misinform , I want just dual lang, eng and slovak, and as we all know google translator is not many times best option...translate is not accurate
so I just want translate my h1,h2...text labels to my charts,
I heard somthing about AJAX that it can reload just some part of web-page and not complete website, but I am not sure if this is my resolution,  not familiar with Ajax so far

Comment: ...so there will be a button to switch lang page, I am just asking if technicaly is it possible...load new text without loading all page

Comment: OK, I tried Google translator, and was not bad :)